# Was the date skip of the Gregorian calender reform understood to skip weekdays accordingly?

Tags: calendar, early-medieval

The date was adjusted, but did the general population, that was more concerned with the weekly rhythm, also adjust their weekday?

Comment: What has your preliminary research shown?

Answer (score 9):

The change over to the Gregorian Calendar happened over a period of [over 300 years](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/julian-gregorian-switch.html) across the western world. Consequently the number of skipped days varied by country depending on when they changed over (the longer they left it, the more days needed to be skipped).

However, the skip only affected the calendar date and not the day of the week. So for example, England's change over in 1752 meant that [Wednesday 2nd September would be followed by Thursday 14th September](http://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofBritain/Give-us-our-eleven-days/).